# How to print chinese characters to the windows console correctly?

Tags: utf-8, fonts, console, echo, chinese-locale

What I want to do is to print Chinese log messages to the windows console.

I did surveying the google and knew that it's related to Chinese font.
But when after setting the Chinese font, at this time incorrect Chinese characters were printed.
I hope to teach me how to solve this if you have some experiences before.

You can simply reproduce this situation.
Create new txt file and write to this "echo '你好！'"，and save this file as 'test.bat'
Run this bat file in the console.

What I want to do is print this Chinese character correctly.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the appropriate code page in the console before running the *bat* file containing Chinese text. [Code page 936 is for simplified Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_936_(Microsoft_Windows)), so call `chcp 936`, and then run `test.bat`.

In my case (on Windows 10) I didn't need to worry about the font being used, since `chcp 936` automatically changed the font to one that can render Chinese characters: **NSimSun**.

[image: ChineseTextInConsole]

Depending on your requirements, it might be preferable to include the call to `chcp 936` at the start of the *bat* file instead.